# Why can't beautifulsoup see this nested div?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I never ask questions here but I am stuck and am spinning my wheels trying to find it.
I am playing around with scraping this week and cannot seem to get the chat comments from this nested div here: https://speedventures1.assettocorsaservers.com/live-timing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = "https://speedventures1.assettocorsaservers.com/live-timing"
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')



print(soup.find(id="chat-container"))
```

I have tried different parsers, I see it rendered in the page, not sure why I cannot access it. Tried accessing around it too and still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because it's generated with JavaScript, which BeautifulSoup doesn't evaluate (it's purely an HTML parser).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you will look into the Html that is fetched by the program, you won't see the chats are fetched as they are being streamed by web-sockets, Try it with selenium as that package provide various ways to interact with the website.

Answer (score 1):

Constantly updating content like chat are generally through polling or websockets. In this case the content is updating through a websocket. You could attempt to set up your own socket to stream this content. There are various packages, with examples, for this such as [websocket](https://pypi.org/project/websocket/).

Finding websockets:

Browser network tab - ws subtab

[image]

Viewing the websocket activity:

[image]